# Will strawberries grow in plant?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, fruit-trees, plant-care, strawberries

Today I went to the supermarket and saw some small pots with strawberry plants. I'd never seen a strawberry plant before, and I wanted to buy it, but decided to check here before.

We live in the Caribbean, so the temperature will always be over 80°F. The plant may receive shade or it can be under the scorching-hot sun (depends on what you guys suggest), but the environment will never be cool. Also, I live in an apartment so the plant will always be in some kind of pot.

With that said, will this strawberry plant actually produce fruit? There's no reason to buy it if I know beforehand that it won't grow anything.

Here’s the plant:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think they will produce strawberries. Just keep them in shadow, and give them a lot of water. Your apartment will not be (hopefully) too hot. In any case the strawberries can survive on hot climate, just they tend to produce fruits on spring, just because they have some more light (they are a forest plant).

My worry is about the lack of flowers. Usually when I buy strawberries plants, I already see the flowers (ok, if I look carefully, I may see one flower bud).

Comment: Thanks, so I should look for plants with flowers or flower buds?

Comment: With so healthy and large leaves, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Strawberries  are often  grown in containers - in some respects it's easier because the fruits dangle, and in a pot, that usually means over the edge rather than sitting on soil in the open ground.

If you are growing indoors, you will probably need to pollinate the flowers yourself so you get fruit - outdoors they are pollinated by wind or insects. If you have the plant/s on a sunny windowsill, you may need to ensure they don't receive hot sun between 11 and 3 because  through a window, it will be much hotter than actually being outdoors.

Information on growing indoors, as well as how to pollinate, here https://greenthumbplanet.com/how-to-grow-strawberries-indoors/

Comment: Thanks. I can place the plant on a small balcony, and it will receive shade during the morning. My biggest concern is that it will also receive the full sun when the sun sets, which is brutal, especially during these months.

Comment: Then you may need to find  a way to provide shade for it...